# Адаптивные блоки фиксированной высоты

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Мне нужно сверстать блоки в три колонки типа
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Блоки могут растягиваться в ширину, но у каждого фиксированная высота. Проблема начинается тогда, когда я пытаюсь сделать их адаптивными. Чтоб добиться хоть примерного поведения я использовал flex, bootstrap, сам пытался, но в итоге остановился на bootstrap. Если слишком широкий экран, то должно быть три колонки, если обычный, то две, и если маленький, то одна. С первым и последним вариантом всё предельно просто. А вот что делать со вторым?

Приведу пример того, что имею:

В три колонки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В одну:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот в две не выходит, остаётся пустое место у красного блока.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что это из-за высоты первой строки и поделать что-то с этим не получится, но возможно есть в данной ситуации какой-то иной подход к написанию этого.

У меня есть идея оставить всё как есть, только после того, как колонок стало две, третью колонку скрывать и с помощью js распределять её элементы по имеющимся двум. Только мне почему-то кажется, что это огромный костыль и должен быть вариант, который я упустил.

Есть идеи?

Answer (score 2):

Для решения подобных вопросов подойдет https://github.com/desandro/masonry и ему подобные.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения проблемы. Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Хм, интересный вариант решения проблемы. А что на счёт производительности скажете. Я посмотрел много материалов, по этому способу, в общем то можно его заставить работать и с сеткой bootstrap. Но будет ли это лучше, чем если я сам вычислю и раскидаю элементы по колонкам?